# Amazon Elasticache Redis cluster - Can't get Endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I need to get the endpoint for a Redis cluster in Amazon Elasticache. The following code works for a Memcached cluster, but not for a Redis:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;

import com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.AmazonElastiCacheClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.model.DescribeCacheClustersRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.model.DescribeCacheClustersResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.model.CacheNode;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.model.CacheCluster;
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.model.Endpoint;

public class Redis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AWSCredentials credentials = 
            new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default").getCredentials();
        AmazonElastiCacheClient amazonClient = new AmazonElastiCacheClient(credentials);
        amazonClient.setRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1);
        DescribeCacheClustersRequest dccRequest = new DescribeCacheClustersRequest();
        dccRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);
        dccRequest.withCacheClusterId("app-001");
        DescribeCacheClustersResult clusterResult = 
            amazonClient.describeCacheClusters(dccRequest);

        CacheCluster cacheCluster = clusterResult.getCacheClusters().get(0);
        System.out.println("cluster: " + cacheCluster);
        System.out.println("endpoint: " + cacheCluster.getConfigurationEndpoint());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
cluster: {CacheClusterId: app-001,ClientDownloadLandingPage: https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticache/home#client-download:,CacheNodeType: cache.r3.large,Engine: redis,EngineVersion: 2.8.19,CacheClusterStatus: available,NumCacheNodes: 1,PreferredAvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a,CacheClusterCreateTime: Thu May 21 11:43:03 CEST 2015,PreferredMaintenanceWindow: mon:04:00-mon:05:00,PendingModifiedValues: {CacheNodeIdsToRemove: [],},CacheSecurityGroups: [],CacheParameterGroup: {CacheParameterGroupName: default.redis2.8,ParameterApplyStatus: in-sync,CacheNodeIdsToReboot: []},CacheSubnetGroupName: default,CacheNodes: [{CacheNodeId: 0001,CacheNodeStatus: available,CacheNodeCreateTime: Thu May 21 11:43:03 CEST 2015,Endpoint: {Address: app-001.3pusxn.0001.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com,Port: 6379},ParameterGroupStatus: in-sync,CustomerAvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a}],AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: true,SecurityGroups: [{SecurityGroupId: sg-3231f657,Status: active}],ReplicationGroupId: app,SnapshotRetentionLimit: 0,SnapshotWindow: 22:00-23:00}
endpoint: null
```

Note how the cluster object contains the endpoint information (key: `Endpoint`), but nevertheless `getConfigurationEndpoint` returns `null`.

How do I get the endpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it usually happens, I found the solution right after posting the question. In Redis you have to access the cache nodes:

```
Endpoint endpoint = cacheCluster.getCacheNodes().get(0).getEndpoint();
```

Comment: I am using aws redis cluster for the first time and I want to know that how you set the data in redis (either using elastic cache or some other redis client like jedis). Which one is recomended??